# WKWebView: Text rendered at wrong size for certain size ranges when multiple elements use that size in the same document

Tags: ios, css, viewport, wkwebview

I know this sounds totally bonkers. Please a look at the following screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

These two screenshots are of a `WKWebView` rendering **exactly the same file.** The only difference is that in the second one, I have duplicated the eight divs you see in the first one (full HTML below).

Just for clarity, the second screenshot has two problems:

1. Between sizes 22px and 28px, the text is all inexplicably **rendered at the same size**, and
2. The actual sizes for text between 16px and 26px are **different from in the first screenshot**, as well as incorrect. The problem seems to go away at the 30px mark. (For what it's worth, I tried this using `pt` units too and the results were similar.)

This is the entirety of my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Repro</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div style="font-size:16px;">The quick fox jumps (16).</div>
     <div style="font-size:18px;">The quick fox jumps (18).</div>
     <div style="font-size:20px;">The quick fox jumps (20).</div>
     <div style="font-size:22px;">The quick fox jumps (22).</div>
     <div style="font-size:24px;">The quick fox jumps (24).</div>
     <div style="font-size:26px;">The quick fox jumps (26).</div>
     <div style="font-size:28px;">The quick fox jumps (28).</div>
     <div style="font-size:30px;">The quick fox jumps (30).</div>

     <div style="font-size:16px;">The quick fox jumps (16).</div>
     <div style="font-size:18px;">The quick fox jumps (18).</div>
     <div style="font-size:20px;">The quick fox jumps (20).</div>
     <div style="font-size:22px;">The quick fox jumps (22).</div>
     <div style="font-size:24px;">The quick fox jumps (24).</div>
     <div style="font-size:26px;">The quick fox jumps (26).</div>
     <div style="font-size:28px;">The quick fox jumps (28).</div>
     <div style="font-size:30px;">The quick fox jumps (30).</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

To be clear, this problem will repro with as few as two lines. Simply using the same font size within the "problem range" twice causes the problem to repro. In other words:

```
<div style="font-size:22px;">The quick fox jumps (22).</div>
<div style="font-size:22px;">The quick fox jumps (22).</div>
```

...is a repro, though you might not notice unless you expect the text to be a certain size.

And this is the code that adds the WKWebView and loads the content (from within `viewDidLoad`):

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.pnlContent.frame configuration:configuration];

webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true;

[self.pnlContent addSubview:webView];

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"html"];
[webView loadFileURL:url allowingReadAccessToURL:url];
```

---

A few things I've been able to determine:

- The problem goes away if I remove the viewpoint tag, or specifically, if I remove anything related to the scale from the `content` attribute.
- The problem only occurs in landscape mode, not portrait.
- The problem goes away if the browser is not made to fill its parent (I've tried it both using `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` as well as by manually adding AutoLayout constraints -- it's the same.)

I'm at wits' end here. Please help!

Comment: Might [`text-size-adjust`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust) be causing this bug?

Comment: @mattsven Yes! Adding `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none` does indeed fix this. Thank you! I'm still investigating some strange issues in my larger project (e.g., not the simplified repro project). This property seems to be applied inconsistently. However, I certainly think I'm on the right track now. Thank you very much!

Comment: You got it. You may want to answer the question yourself in case anyone else has the same problem.

Comment: Okay, cool. I didn't want to take that away from you if you wanted the points for the answer. I'll research a little more and post an answer if you haven't done so first in a few days.

Comment: Feel free. I think your answer will be more informed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the culprit here was [`text-size-adjust`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust) (big thanks to @mattsven for the assist here).

You'll probably want to use both `text-size-adjust` and the vendor-specific `-webkit-text-size-adjust`.

In case it helps anyone, when I added this at the `body` level, it did not seem to be uniformly applied to my document, though I think it might be complicated by a `zoom:0.5` I have at the `body` level (long story). However, for what it's worth, I found that if I applied it specifically to the classes that were experiencing the weird render issues I described in my original question, I was able to correct the issue.

Hope this help someone!

Comment: I'll also throw some information about why I think this happens for anyone else curious: `text-size-adjust`'s default value is `auto`, which enables Mobile Safari's text inflation algorithm. Going by your example above, that algorithm seems to be a. scaling all font sizes by a factor `f` (however that's determined) and b. enforcing a maximum font size (in the example above, that's `22 * f`)